# Labview serial port event callback possible?

Tags: event-handling, serial-port, labview

Is it possible to receive data from a serial port in Labview using an event callback? Similar to DataReceived event callback in .NET serial port class? If yes, I would appreciate a link to an example VI. All the examples I have seen use the synchronous send/receive approach. I would assume that the callback event, if possible, must happen in a separate thread.

My device streams (ASCII) data out very fast, about 1000 data points per sec

Comment: I'm interested to know why you're thinking of doing it this way - are you having problems dealing with the received data at the moment?

Answer (score 3):

You could poll the serial port and if the number of bytes exceeds a threashold (I used samples of 4 bytes), read that data and generate a user event. In another thread you could handle the events like normal events:

[image]

Comment: What do you have wired to the stop condition for the bottom loop? I am assuming it's coming from the `Timeout` pane.

Comment: Most likely a stop button in it's own event case